# Fragment having blank content at initial startup or after returning from another activity

Tags: java, android, tabs, fragment

I have an application with two tabs (first tab, second tab). However during start up or returning from another activity, the fragment of first tab is blank. The fragment only will be shown after I click on second tab then the first tab. 
Another question, is there any way to have second tab display on initial start up instead of the first tab?

```
    //
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_tab_base);

    simpleFrameLayout = findViewById(R.id.simpleFrameLayout);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.simpleTabLayout);

    TabLayout.Tab firstTab = tabLayout.newTab();
    firstTab.setText("Income");
    tabLayout.addTab(firstTab);

    TabLayout.Tab secondTab = tabLayout.newTab();
    secondTab.setText("Expenses");
    tabLayout.addTab(secondTab);

    // I try to set the fragment but startup but no effect
    if (fragment==null)
        fragment = new IncomeTab();

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener()       {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new IncomeTab();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new ExpenseTab();
                    break;
            }
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, fragment);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            ft.commit();
        }            
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason for it being blank is simply because the Fragment just isn't shown yet.

A fragment will only be shown after you commit the FragmentTransaction that places the Fragment onto the screen, however, in your code this only happens when a Tab is pressed. Therefore, no fragment will be shown, until you press on a tab.

```
// I try to set the fragment but startup but no effect
if (fragment==null)
    fragment = new IncomeTab();
```

This code is also useless because it's not being done through a FragmentTransaction, you're simply creating a new IncomeTab fragment and doing nothing with it.

The fix is the following:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_tab_base);

    simpleFrameLayout = findViewById(R.id.simpleFrameLayout);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.simpleTabLayout);

    TabLayout.Tab firstTab = tabLayout.newTab();
    firstTab.setText("Income");
    tabLayout.addTab(firstTab);

    TabLayout.Tab secondTab = tabLayout.newTab();
    secondTab.setText("Expenses");
    tabLayout.addTab(secondTab);

    replaceFragment(1);

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            replaceFragment(int tabPosition)
        }            
    });
}

private void replaceFragment(int tabPosition){
    switch (tab.getPosition()) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new IncomeTab();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new ExpenseTab();
            break;
    }
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, fragment);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.commit();
}
```

You can show any fragment you want when starting the app by making sure to perform a FragmentTransaction on that fragment.